# Distinguish odd and even pages in a same paragraph

Tags: macros

I have some margin notes in a text, and want them to be aligned in different way according to the odd or even pages.
I created this command :

```
\newcommand{\notemarge}[1]{\ifodd\c@page 
 \marginpar{\raggedright\scriptsize #1} \else 
 \marginpar{\raggedleft\scriptsize #1} \fi}
```

which works in main cases, but not when there are two notes in a same paragraph on different pages. The reason : `\thepage` changes only with a new paragraph.

I tried this :

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newcounter{masterpage}\setcounter{masterpage}{1}
\AtBeginShipout{\refstepcounter{masterpage}}
```

but not resolves.

How fix it ?

Comment: `\marginpar` has an optional argument to control this. remove the tests and `\marginpar[left version]{right version}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not usefully test the parity or even the value of the page counter at the point that expandable tests such as `\ifodd` are expanded in the paragraph. Linebreaking and so page breaking happens after macro expansion and so `\c@page` will always have the same value while macros in a single paragraph are executed, even if that paragraph is long and covers several pages. Only when the end of paragraph is reached will the page breaker split things into pages and increment the counter as it ships out each page.

For this reason `\marginpar` allows you to store two versions of the note one for the left and one for the right, (it doesn't always get it right unfortunately) but should probably work.

```
\marginpar[left version]{right version}
```